# Отмена покупки в приложении в Google Play

Tags: java, android, google-play

Я использую com.anjlab.android.iab.v3:library:1.0.44

У меня 2 вопроса по работе с встроенными покупками в Google Play.

1. Пользователи начали массово делать покупки и возвращать средства в моём приложении. Так как это не подписка - после отмены покупки и возврата средств за неё - в приложении эта покупка сохраняется. Я понимаю, что я могу сам постоянно спрашивать у гугла - есть ли у пользователя покупка или нет, и делать нужные мне действия. Однако, что удивительно, в гугле почти нет информации по тому, как сделать "защиту от возврата денег в android". Либо пишут, что защиты от этого нет. Почему так и что с этим возможно сделать?
2. Я попробовал сам отменять сделанные мною покупки. Если я отменяю тестовую - то после удаления приложения и чистой переустановки всё ок, но если я отменяю настоящую, то гугл считает, что отмененная покупка у меня таки есть и возобновляет мне её. Я что-то делаю не так или чего-то не понимаю?

```
@Override
    public void onPurchaseHistoryRestored() {
        /*
         * Вызывается один раз при первом запуске после установки или переустановки приложения.
         * Служит для получения приобретённых ранее покупок, например, на другом устройстве
         */
        for (String sku : bp.listOwnedProducts())
            myDB.writeStatPurchase(sku);
        finish();
        startActivity(getIntent());
    }
```

Comment: уже давно покупки нужно подтверждать иначе они автоматом возвращаются пользователю, используйте стандартную библиотеку она хорошо описана в документации